# stuck in creating query to fetch the result from database?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

i am creating a project called discussion forum in servlets...
    but i stuck in the query to fetch the result from database with respect to the given topic...
    i make a servlet named index in which there is a topics when i clicked the topic i got some kind of error like **Unknown column 'pepsi' in 'where clause'** in the MessageDisplayed servlet...i think there is a problem in the query...
    the coding of index servlet is:

```
@WebServlet("/Index")
public class Index extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/df";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String USER = "root";
        String PASS = "root";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, USER, PASS);
            out.print("<html><body>");
            out.print("<a href='PostTopic'><input type='submit' value='Post New Topic'></a><br><br>");
            String sql = "select topic_name from topic";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                String topic_name = rs.getString("topic_name");
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("topic_name", topic_name);

                out.print("<a href='MessageDisplayed'>");
                out.print(topic_name);out.print("</a>");
                out.print("<br>");
            }

            out.print("</body></html>");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
        out.close();
    }

}
```

and the coding of MessageDisplayed servlet is:

```
public class MessageDisplayed extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/df";
         String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
         String USER = "root";
         String PASS = "root";
        try{
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, USER, PASS);
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            String topic = (String) session.getAttribute("topic_name");
            String sql = "select user_name,comment from comments where topic_name="+topic;
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        //  ps.setString(1, topic);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString("user_name");
                String comment = rs.getString("comment");
                out.print("<html><body>");
                out.print("Name : "+name);out.print("<br>");out.print("Message : "+comment);out.print("<br>");
                out.print("</body></html>");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
        out.close();
    }

}
```

the database has 2 tables topic table(topic_id,topic_name) and a comments table(comment_id,comment,user_name,topic_id) the insertion is working fine...
but i can't be able to fetch the results
please help me out as soon as possible....

Comment: topic_name name column is not available in comments table ,you put the topic_name in where clause. If  you want to retrieve topic name then you need to use join on topic and comments table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think error is in this line

```
String sql = "select user_name,comment from comments where topic_name="+topic;
```

Moreover the way you are using is not the right way of using PreparedStatement.

Use this way

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select user_name,comment from comments where topic_name=?");
ps.setString(1,topic);
```